# Select variable with SQLite in Java

Tags: java, sqlite

At the moment I have a table that look like this:

```
ID       VAR1   VAR2
SN453    1      blablabla
SN453    2      blablabla
AK221    1      blablabla
AK221    2      blablabla
```

What I want to do is to select VAR1 and VAR2 for a given ID. ID is in a String variable, I would use this:

```
ps = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT VAR1, VAR2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = ?");
```

How can I tell SQLite to pick the ID value from my string variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ps = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT VAR1, VAR2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID =?";
ps.setString(1, myStringVariable); 
           //^ '1' is the index of the ? you're assigning
           //you'd have multiple setters if you had more than one parameter (?)
```

When using a parameterized query, you need to just assign the variables.

[More information can be found in this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

And [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)) is the documentation for the `setString(int parameterIndex, String x)` method from the `PreparedStatement` class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the desired value to the placeholder ("?") that you put into our SQL statement. Placeholders are referenced by position in the statement, so you need to bind a value to placeholder #1. Something like this would do the trick:

```
ps.setString(1, id);
```

Once you've done that, `ps.executeQuery()` should give you a `ResultSet` that you can use to extract your results.

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for `java.sql.PreparedStatement` for full details.